# How to reorder the items in a legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to change the order in which legend items appear.  I've spent about an hour at this, with no results.

Here's an example setup:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(0)
d <- data.frame(x = runif(3), y = runif(3), a = c('1', '3', '10'))
```

And here's one of the many things I've tried:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
    geom_point(size=7, aes(color = a, order = as.numeric(a)))
```

[image]

(My naive hope, of course, was that the legend items would be shown in the numeric order: 1, 3, 10.)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`ggplot` will usually order your factor values according to the `levels()` of the factor. You are best of making sure that is the order you want otherwise you will be fighting with a lot of function in R, but you can manually change this by manipulating the color scale:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
    geom_point(size=7, aes(color = a)) + 
    scale_color_discrete(breaks=c("1","3","10"))
```

Answer (score 12):

The order of legend labels can be manipulated by reordering and changing values in column `a` to the factor: `d$a <- factor(d$a, levels = d$a)`

So your code would look like this

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(0)
d <- data.frame(x = runif(3), y = runif(3), a = c('1', '3', '10'))

d$a <- factor(d$a, levels = d$a)

ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point(size=7, aes(color = a))
```

And the ouptut
[image]

Note, than now in legend: 1 is red, 3 is green and 10 is blue color

Comment: Thanks!  I upvoted this answer because it provides useful information, but I'll hold out for answer that does not require modifying the underlying `data.frame`.  Somehow, I find it hard to believe that `ggplot2` would require changing the underlying `data.frame` in order to change something as superficial as the ordering of items in a legend.